# Float items either way

Tags: html, image, css-float

I'm working on an image page but can't figure out how to fill the gaps. I'm using float:left but that leaves some spaces blank.

You can find the image page here: http://ianbauters.no-ip.org/kinno/pages/images.html

Comment: take a look at this -> http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about this blank space?

[image: Screenshot]

It is normal behaviour of CSS floating. If you want to fill the gap you should use JavaScript library like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to divide your page into three and each episode take photos (without float)